# Deserializing custom Object types using gson - failure to deserialize Map

Tags: java, json, gson

I have a method which uses gson to deserialize custom objects. The method takes in a specific class type so that it can deserialize objects of any kind. It looks something like this:

```
public <T> T getMyCustomObject(String jsonString, class<T> classType) {
    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    T obj = gson.fromJson(jsonString, classType);
    return obj;
}
```

Now, I want to serialize an entry from DynamoDB which is a `Map<String, AttributeValue>`
My method call to that function looks like:

```
Type typeOfHashMap = new TypeToken<Map<String, AttributeValue>>() { }.getType();
Map<String, AttributeValue> attributeValue = getMyCustomObject(jsonString, typeOfHashMap.getClass());
```

My json string is completely valid, but then I receive an exception -

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.$Gson$Types$ParameterizedTypeImpl cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

What exactly am I doing wrong? Is it wrong that I take in a generic type and Java type erasure is screwing that up? Or should I not be using TypeToken at all?

Comment: Why are you using `getMyCustomObject` at all? Just `gson.fromJson(jsonString, typeOfHashMap())`.

Comment: I need that method since I am deserializing objects of different kind.

Comment: `Gson` already has those methods, you don't need an extra wrapper. It'll actually break under other conditions. The type bound to `T` at the call site doesn't propagate within the method.

Comment: If I remove the classType, I'll lose the ability to have that method deserialize any type of object. The method works completely fine for any Custom POJO. It specifically fails for a Map type.

Comment: Sorry, but I am a bit confused, if it is broken, how is it that it works fine for other POJO's, but fails for a Map?

Comment: Actually ignore those last comments, I thought you were creating a `TypeToken` within `getMyCustomObject`, your `getMyCustomObject` is just redundant. The point of `TypeToken` is to be used directly (through its `Type`) with the `Gson` instance with the generic type you want to deserialize. You should be using what I suggested originally. `gson.fromJson(jsonString, typeOfHashMap)`.

Comment: Well as I said, I am using the method to deserialize customObjects and that's the reason why it takes in a generic type. If I do a TypeToken on a generic type, it would return the type Object (Thanks to Java type erasure). So I do need the method. My other puzzled question would that as to why it works fine with other custom objects, but fails specifically for  a Map?

Comment: There are a lot of parts to this...The `Class` type is not sufficient to describe generic types. For that reason, Gson uses the type token "hack", since a `Type` **can** describe a generic type. However, Gson can not enforce compile time type safety. **You cannot get around this.** Right now, you're not telling Gson to deserialize a `Map<String, AttributeValue>`. You're telling it to deserialize `typeOfHashMap.getClass()`, where `typeOfHashMap` is  a `ParameterizedType`. Your `TypeToken` (and its `Type`) is describing the `Map<..>` so use it directly, as intended by Gson.